# Grouping within a view

Tags: mysql, sql, view, group-by

This is something I'm trying to get my head around...  I have three tables like this:

```
Practice
* PracticeID
* PracticeName

Group
* GroupID
* Sales
* Salaries
* Overheads

Values
* PracticeID
* GroupID
* Income
* Expense
```

What I am looking to do is prepare a view to sum up the income and expenses in Values by the group names in the Group table.  I can get as far as a row by row summary, but I'm having the issue on how to include the group clause in the code I currently have, which is below:

```
SELECT Practice.PracticeName, Group.Groupname, Values.Income, Values.Expenses    
FROM     values INNER JOIN
                  Practice ON values.PracticeID = Practice.PracticeID INNER JOIN
                  Group ON Values.NominalGroupID = Group.GroupID
```

Comment: Your Group table definition does not include the GroupName column while your query does.

Comment: In addition you don't mention the Practice table in the query description, but it's used in the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT Practice.PracticeName, Group.Groupname, SUM(Values.Income) as SumIncome, SUM(Values.Expenses ) as SumExpences   
FROM     values INNER JOIN
                  Practice ON values.PracticeID = Practice.PracticeID INNER JOIN
                  Group ON Values.NominalGroupID = Group.GroupID
Group By Group.Groupname
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table definition does not really include all the columns you used in your example so I'm not sure if that's what you are looking for:

```
SELECT Group.Groupname
    ,SUM(Values.Income) as Income
    ,SUM(Values.Expenses ) as Expenses
FROM Group
INNER JOIN Value ON Values.GroupID = Group.GroupID
Group By Group.Groupname
```